# License issue in SOAP UI pro-4.5.2

Tags: soap, soapui, license-key

Good Morning all

I am looking for help on a licensing issue in SOAP UI.

I have a purchased license od SOAP UI pro and tried to activate the license on my new Windowa-7/64 bit DELL system.
i am unable to activate it in SOAP UI pro 4.5.2.

http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/i ... enses.html

Every time I try to activate online now this is the message I receive an error message

***Error 
Unable to activate license.
The license can not be activated as the number of allowed copies has been exceeded.***

How can I get my new license activated?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be resolved if you put an old version of soap ui first and then start updating the license file with the new one.
I am using 4.6 Soap Ui pro and faced it again.
This might not be an issue of Soap Ui , but is the problem of updating the old license (which is expired ) or adding a new license in the existing Soap Ui with the new license.

please let me know , if there is some doubts .

Answer (score -1):

Contact SoapUI support http://www.soapui.org/Support/support-overview.html . I think they can help you.

Comment: Note that answers that are barely more than a link to an external site are discouraged.

Comment: @A.E.Drew I think you want an answer to your problem, and if a link provides you the answer I would say this is fine. In this case I think  this is perfectly okay since link guide him to solve the problem. Don't follow rules blindly unless you understand the purpose of it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use an online tool that is more adapted to SOAP tests and does not require that you install anything. Try https://www.wsdltophp.com. Why using a installed software to do online stuffs (SOAP) when online tool exists?